# Output nested JSON into <ul> with sub-list items

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I have a JSON and am having trouble formatting it into a list with sub-list items. I have it somewhat working, but could just be missing something simple, which I hope you guys can help me with.

My JSON looks like this:

```
var json = {
    "siteMap": [
        {
            "title": "Red",
            "link": "red.html",
            "subPageArray": [
                { "subTitle": "SubLink1", "link": "test1.html" },
                { "subTitle": "SubLink2", "link": "test2.html" }
            ]
        },
        {
            "title": "Blue",
            "link": "blue.html",
            "subPageArray": [
                { "subTitle": "SubLink1", "link": "test1.html" },
                { "subTitle": "SubLink2", "link": "test2.html" }
            ]
        },
        {
            "title": "Green",
            "link": "green.html"
        },
        {
            "title": "Yellow",
            "link": "yellow.html",
            "subPageArray": [
                { "subTitle": "SubLink1", "link": "test1.html" },
                { "subTitle": "SubLink2", "link": "test2.html" }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

If an object does not have a 'subPageArray', I would like there to NOT be a sub-list under that item.

My jQuery looks like this:

```
$.each(json.siteMap, function (i, val) {
    var i = 0,
        a = i++,
        data = "<li class='topLevel'><a href='/" + this.link + "'>" + this.title + "</a><ul><li class='subLevel'><a href='/" + this.subPageArray[i].link + "'>" + this.subPageArray[a].subTitle + "</a></li></ul></li>";
        i++;    
        $(data).appendTo(".siteMapContent ul");
});
```

And my HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="siteMapContent">
    <ul></ul>
</div>
```

---

I am hoping that the end result will look like this:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="red.html">Red</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="test1.html">SubLink1</a></li>
            <li><a href="test2.html">SubLink2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="blue.html">Blue</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="test1.html">SubLink1</a></li>
            <li><a href="test2.html">SubLink2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="green.html">Green</a></li>
    <li><a href="yellow.html">Yellow</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="test1.html">SubLink1</a></li>
            <li><a href="test2.html">SubLink2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Could you make an jsfiddle ?

Comment: Here's the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/Hp8ZY/

Comment: @NickJ checkout my answer it working..

Comment: You need to watch out to write clean code too as your JS snippet is quite confusing. First why have $.each return the index as "i" if it is to declare "i" inside the callback scope as 0, just have it as index and ignore it. a = i++ is to avoid too.

Comment: Besides "standard" appending, try with javascript templating engine like Handlebars(or any other)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$.each(json.siteMap, function (i, val) {
    var data="<li class='topLevel'><a href='/" + this.link + "'>" + this.title + "</a><ul>";
    if(this.subPageArray!=undefined){  // TO check if subPageArray exists here in case of Green
       for (i = 0; i < this.subPageArray.length; ++i) {
           //Adding the internal li
            data += "<li class='subLevel'><a href='/" + this.subPageArray[i].link + "'>" + this.subPageArray[i].subTitle + "</a></li>";
       }
    }
       data+="</ul></li>";

        $(data).appendTo(".siteMapContent .hii");
});
```

And your html code:I added a class name to ul so dynamically generated code doesn't get added to the inner ul

```
<div class="siteMapContent">
    <ul class="hii"></ul>
</div>
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Hp8ZY/3/

Comment: It works but the code is not very clean as still based on the poster one. Same as my comment on the original post but here more confusion as a get assign i which was just overwritten in the line above. Then i is again declare in the for loop and a is then again i inside the loop yet it's never used.

Answer (score 2):

This is not the cleanest way but it does the job http://jsfiddle.net/8k6nw/

You need to of course iterate over the subitem if present.

```
var html = "<ul>";

json.siteMap.forEach(function(item) {

    html += "<li><a href='"+item.link+"'>"+item.title+"</a>";

    if (item.subPageArray) {

        html += "<ul>";

        item.subPageArray.forEach(function(subitem) {

              html += "<li><a href='"+subitem.link+"'>"+subitem.subTitle+"</a></li>";      

        });

        html += "</ul>";

    }

    html += "</li>";
});

document.body.innerHTML = html + "</ul>";
```

Comment: This works great, however, is there a way to use it without 'document.body.innerHTML'. This is wiping away the rest of the page content.

Comment: This code is just taken from the jsfiddle which require document.body. I was illustrating more than providing the code you need. Just use html += "</ul>"; instead and do what you need with the html variable.